# A problem in n-dimesnsional Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, product-measure

I found myself completely at loss while dealing with the following problem in measure theory (specificly in the field of product-measures):

Given a finite sequence $\{a_1,...,a_n\}\in\mathbb{R}$ of positive numbers, show that the function $f(\vec x)=\frac{1}{x_1^{a_1}+...+x_n^{a_n}}$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies
$$\int_{{[0,\infty)}^n\setminus[0,1]^n}f d\lambda<\infty$$

if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{a_k}<1$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $N=1,2,\dots$ let $S_N$ be the set of $x$ with $x_j>0$ for all $j$ and $$2^N\le x_1^{a_1}+\dots+x_n^{a_n}<2^{N+1},$$so that $$f(x)\sim 2^{-N}\quad(x\in S_N).$$It follows that that the integral in question is finite if and only if $$\sum_{N=1}^\infty2^{-N}m(S_N)<\infty$$

Note that $$S_{N+1}=T(S_N),$$
where $$Tx=(2^{1/a_1}x_1,\dots,2^{1/a_n}x_n).$$
Hence $$m(S_N)=c2^{N\sum\frac1{a_j}}$$(by induction),
and so $\sum 2^{-N}m(S_N)<\infty$ if and only if $\sum\frac1{a_j}<1$.

Comment: Hello David, could you please elaborate on the statement $S_{N+1} = T(S_N)$?  I do not see why that's true

Comment: @EZSlaver Have you tried to just work it out? It's just a simple calculation. Say $y=Tx$. Then $y_j^{a_j}=2x_j^{a_j}$, so $2^{N+1}\le\sum y_j^{a_j}<2^{N+2}$ if and only if $2^N\le\sum x_j^{a_j}<2^{N+1}$. (Now you might elaborate on why you're leaving your answer there even though it's wrong. The idea is that the site should be a place where people can find valid information...)

Comment: Yeah, I did that, and it worked out. I was too fast to ask the question. That's why I marked your answer the solution.  Thanks

Comment: @EZSlaver Regarding both my comments: I was confused about who was the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=[0,\infty)^n\backslash[0,1]^n$.

$\Leftarrow]$ Suppose $\sum{1/a_k}<1$. Then, $a_k>1$ for all $k$. Then, by Tonelli's Theorem, the integral is finite (here, we used that $\int_{(1,\infty)}1/x^pdx<\infty$ for $p>1$).

$\Rightarrow]$ Suppose $\sum{1/a_k}\ge 1$. Then, $1/a_k\ge 1$ for some $k$. Again, by Tonelli's Theorem, we can suppose $k=1$. Then, $\int_1^\infty f(x_1,...,x_n)d\lambda(x_1)=\infty$, and thus, all the integral is infinity.

Comment: I understand the general idea, but I have a problem with the use of Fubini, though even though the function is obviously measurable, It is not strictly positive or trivially in $L^1 (\mu) $, so the use of Fubini's theorem doesn't seem to me to be justifiable - especially in the second direction.

Comment: @EZSlaver you're right. It must be Tonelli's Theorem. Note that inded $1_Af:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is non negative (it is not necessarily strictly positiveness)

Comment: Oh, I feel bad. I forgot that the domain on which the function is declared is positive (and considered negative values in my head). Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: Erm, $\sum 1/a_k\ge1$ does not imply $1/a_k\ge1$ for some $k$. For example $1/2+1/2+1/2>1$.

Comment: The first half is also wrong; the error is somewhere in the details you left out. At least it's wrong, _assuming_ that the original statement is correct: If the first half of your argument is correct it shows that if $a_k>1$ for all $k$ then the integral is finite. So the stated result would show that if $a_k>1$ for all $k$ then $\sum 1/a_k < 1$, which is not true. (Again because $1/2+1/2+1/2>1$.)